# html and CSS question, Why is my list element misaligned slightly on the left?

Tags: html, css

I am learning web dev and it's my first project working on a "to-do" app.
The li element inside of div classed "tasks" with brown background color seems to be off on the left side. Even in a default setting, the li element takes the whole right hand side but left-hand side starts oddly after few spaces.
What is causing it to act this way and how do I fix it?
I have linked the file as well for clarity.
[codepen](https://codepen.io/dipak1993/pen/mdXgpMN)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do Lists</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>To Do Lists</h1>
        <input type="text">
        <button>Add</button>
        <button>clear</button>
    </div>

    <div class="tasks">
        <ul>
            <li>
                List 1
                <button>Done</button>
                <button>incomplete</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                List 2
                <button>Done</button>
                <button>incomplete</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                List 3
                <button>Done</button>
                <button>incomplete</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

    .header {
    background-color: aqua;
    border-style: dashed;
    margin: 2% 20%;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.tasks {
    background-color: beige;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto 10%;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: .4rem;
    background-color: rgb(95, 162, 102);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `ul` has default padding which is causing this behaviour. Every browser has its own default value, though recommended from W3C is `40px`. To remove the space you can simply set padding of `ul` to `0`.

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Also for future references, you can use INSPECT ELEMENT to see what's causing this issue so you maybe able to better pin point the root cause and handle things.

Keep learning, keep coding!

Answer (score 1):

`ul` has default padding to remove the spacing you can add CSS `ul` padding `0`.

```css
.header {
  background-color: aqua;
  border-style: dashed;
  margin: 2% 20%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.tasks {
  background-color: beige;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto 10%;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0.4rem;
  background-color: rgb(95, 162, 102);
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">
      <h1>To Do Lists</h1>
      <input type="text" />
      <button>Add</button>
      <button>clear</button>
    </div>

    <div class="tasks">
      <ul>
        <li>
          List 1
          <button>Done</button>
          <button>incomplete</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          List 2
          <button>Done</button>
          <button>incomplete</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          List 3
          <button>Done</button>
          <button>incomplete</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```